# Is it possible to registerForContextMenu from MPAndroidChart's onValueSelected method?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, android-contextmenu

I'm new to both Android and [MPandroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). So far I managed to play around with MPandroidChart, thanks to its example. I need help and stuck on this part.
Is it possible to call/show contextmenu when a value is selected from the chart? (PieChart)

```
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
 //.. show context menu
 }
```

I would like to display couple of menu-option, when a value is highlighted in chart. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.

You can of course execute any code you want in the `onValueSelected(...)` method.